# Key Binding to a button element in c# wpf

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I have a print button in my application which prints the receipt. However user prefers having a shortcut key (no combination with shift or Alt, instead it should be just a single key press say F2). On press of this button, I should call the printReceipt() method which I was calling on click of print button.

I am trying to add a keybinding to the user control as the button element is in user control like below

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
<KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{Binding PrintReceipt}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

I am a beginner and can anyone suggest me what is the best way to handle such use case?

Comment: Try to set the KeyBinding on the MainWindow. If this doesn't work can you add the code of the command?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to PreviewKeyDown of the form. There you can obtain the model from DataContext property and call PrintReciept.

This does not violate MVVM principles and is easy to understand. Also, not much magic happening imho.

Comment: Woow. That worked!!! Thanks Rob. Btw.. won't this be checking or calling the function that we have written on PreviewKeyDown on every keypress of the whole form? Won't it cause any performace issue?

Comment: It will but I see this as an advantage. Anywhere on the screen you can press F2 and you will call the print receipt. I think this is exactly what the user wants. Also, I think it goes without saying that you should check if the pressed key is in fact F2 and just ignore everything else. This is not a performance issue.